# VBA PPT Event triggered when chart is added

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to write an VBA-Code that triggers whenever a chart is added in PPT. So far I found
this list: [Link](http://youpresent.co.uk/powerpoint-application-events-in-vba/). However the options don't work, I thought maybe using "AfterShapeSizeChange", since it comes kind of close. But even this event does not work/trigger.

Anybody has an idea what I could use?

Kind regards

Comment: I don't think you'll find an event that does what you need. Instead, you will probably have to write a chart insertion macro that replaces the one in PowerPoint. Can you tell us more details of what problem you're trying to solve? There may be an alternate method.

Comment: PowerPoint does not have available events like Excel and Word do. [Try this ...](http://skp.mvps.org/autoevents.htm)

Comment: @John Korchok: Thank you for your response! Whenever a chart is inserted, it should directly be formated (e.g. data series should be set to a certain font size).

Comment: @user10186832: Thank you, but I would like to avoid using add-ins from external sources (liability reasons).

Comment: user10186832 is mistaken; PPT does have events that you can trap via VBA code in an add-in (which is exactly what the third-party add-in mentioned is doing). The event I'd look at would be Selection Change, but you'd need to hang other code around it to determine whether the newly selected shape is a chart and if so, whether it's a new chart or a previously existing one. Using .Tags could help with that.  There's more info about events here:  https://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00004_Make_your_VBA_code_in_PowerPoint_respond_to_events.htm

Comment: I don't think you need code. Instead, format the chart with your preferred text sizes, then save it as a _Chart Template_. Then, when creating a new chart, apply that template. Voila! The text is the correct size! https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/save-a-custom-chart-as-a-template-259a5f9d-a9ec-4b3f-94b6-9f5e55187f2a

Comment: @John Korchok: Yes that was my initial plan, but I would have to do it for all data series individually and I don't know how many data series there will be in advance. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Create a chart with the maximum number of data series that are ever likely to occur. Format them all, then save as a chart template. The template will remember the formatting for any number of series.

Comment: Thank you John! I assume that there as no other way than to format all these data series one by one, correct?

Comment: @SteveRindsberg I stand corrected!